# Cypher query to create multiple nodes and relationships

Tags: nosql, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to write a Cypher query to create multiple nodes and relationships in one query. The documentation on using `CREATE` clauses in Cypher states that it's not possible to create multiple nodes of different types in a singular `CREATE` clause.

However it hints that I should be able to break it up into multiple `CREATE`'s. A couple of similar answers I have read point to the same solution as well. I've tried doing this and keep getting the response error.

```
Error: If you create multiple elements, you can only create one of each.
```

Here is a brief outline of what I'm trying to do.

1. Create an `item` node.
2. Create multiple `representation` nodes.
3. Create a relationship between the created `item` node and an existing `stack` node.
4. Create multiple relationships between the created `item` node and the created `representation` nodes.

This is the query I'm currently using which attempts to break up all the individual parts of the `CREATE` process into individual steps.

```
START stack=node({stack})
CREATE (item {item}) 
CREATE (representations {representations})
CREATE (stack)-[:Item]->(item)
CREATE (item)-[:Representation]->(representations)
RETURN item, representations
```

I've tried several variations of the above query, including putting the creation of the `item` and `representation` nodes at the beginning of the query.

I would really appreciate any advice. I really don't want to resort to making multiple database calls if it can be avoided.

Comment: Which API are you using to execute cypher, the embedded Java or some REST driver/client?

Comment: @jjaderberg I'm using a the [nodejs neo4j client](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j) which is a REST client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your representations a list ?  Then you can only have that as the single create statement.

I assume Neo4j 1.9 from your syntax.

What you can do though is to use `FOREACH`

```
START stack=node({stack})
CREATE (item {item}) 
CREATE (stack)-[:Item]->(item)
FOREACH (r in {representations} : 
   CREATE (representation {r}), (item)-[:Representation]->(representation)
)
MATCH (item)-[:Representation]->(representations)
RETURN item, representations
```

Comment: You are correct the `representations` are a list and I'm using Neo4j 1.9. I will give your `FOREACH` solution a try and see how it works.

Just out of curiosity what is the reason the `CREATE` clause can only be used once if you're creating nodes from  list.

Also it might be worth updating the documentation to explicitly state this as currently it reads.

"When you do this, you can’t create anything else in the same CREATE clause."

Which I interpreted to mean you can use multiple `CREATE` clauses.

Comment: @michael-hunger I tried your example and I keep getting a syntax error `Error: ')' expected but 'C'` after some fiddling it's being caused by the second `CREATE` clause in the `FOREACH`. I had a go at fixing it but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You can also use commas between the statements in CREATE, I edit to reflect that.

Comment: I am able to run an equivalent query with neo4j 2.0 and literal maps instead of parameters. Could you update your question with exact query, parameters and full error message?